# VB6 not responding in windows server 2016

Tags: vb6, windows-server-2016

We have a set of applications written in VB6 running on a Windows 2003 server . X connects to a DB and writes some files. Y reads those and then writes the input files for Z.

We have a .bat which launches apps X, Y and Z. When X finishes it then launches Y and so on. They are independent but run in sequence.

We used a tool [CPAU](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/cpau/) (starting process with **runas** ) to launch these applications with the login of the user.

The .bat file works like this :

```
cpau.exe -u user -p pass -profile -wait -ex "d:\recette\X.exe
cpau.exe -u user -p pass -profile -wait -ex "d:\recette\Y.exe
cpau.exe -u user -p pass -profile -wait -ex "d:\recette\Z.exe
```

It worked fine until we moved them into Windows 2016.

The problem: X,Y and Z are randomly not responding. They take 0% CPU and sit idle forever.

Once the problem happens, all the apps launched by the .bat don't respond. That means if Y isn't responding, and I kill Y by *taskmanager*, Z which is launched next by the .bat and doesn't respond either.

However, when I start the app Z by myself, it can run normally.

I installed the Visual C++ Runtime 2008, 2010, 2012,2013 and 2015 (x84 and x64 for all of them) and 2017(x86).

Does anyone have an idea why these apps are freezing randomly?

Comment: You can verify that it's not `cpau.exe` that is freezing randomly first by starting `cmd.exe /c dir` or something bound to be just working fine.

Comment: Simple approach is to add some debug output (text log or even MessageBox to the EXEs and see where they are getting stuck. But maybe watching them with process monitor would get you to the same point

Comment: It seems you're passing user and PW per command line for CPAU. So why use this instead of the native `RunAs` command? The main "selling point" of CPAU is to - quote from the site you linked _" create job files and encode the id, password, and command line in a file so it can be used by normal users"_. Which you don't seem to do.

Comment: @HelO'Ween You cannot supply password on the command line with `RunAs`. This is the only reason CPAU-a-like tools proliferate (and ruin security for everyone).

Comment: Did you add any debug output to see at what point X Y Z are actually getting stuck? You need more debugging information.

Comment: @wqw: I refer you to the [/savecred](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11)) parameter of RunAs. 1st time calling `RunAs /savecred /user:user "executable"` will prompt you for the PW and store it. Further calls for the same user _(implying the PW hasn't changed, ofc)_ will use the stored PW.

Comment: @HelO'Ween: Yes, `/savecred` is a totally awkward option impl to save their face. Even with the option available CPAU-a-like tools are a fact and used a lot however buggy they are.